# How to use internal functions of a given package in my own functions

Tags: r, namespaces, r-package

I want to write a function using internal functions of a given R package (for instance httr) without having to refer to these methods as `httr:::method_of_httr_package` in the *body* of my function (I do not want to use `:::`).

I try to change the environment of my function such as in:

```
enviroment(my_func) <- base::asNamespace("httr")
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I assume you have a reason not to use `library` or `require` right?

Comment: As far as I know, using `library` or `require` will load the functions of a given package, but not its methods (which can be access through the triple colon `:::`)

Comment: If the functions in **httr** that you want really are not exported (you're using the word "method", but I think you mean exported/un-exported), then that's sort of fundamentally unsafe and not recommended, so R isn't likely to go out of its way to make that easy for you to do. On the other hand, simply using `:::` will work (until it breaks, because using un-exported stuff from other packages is risky).

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of exactly why you need this. It seems likely this is an xy problem, and there is a better way to do what you really. need, rather than what you think you want. As @joran says, this is risky and discouraged. That said. `assignInNamespace` may be what you are looking for. But I really think there will be a better approach once you let us know your use case.

Comment: @joran you are write, I am talking about the non-exported elements.

Comment: @dww I am using the package `rtweet` which is able to request the Twitter REST API but the default authentification is user authentification. I want to use application-only authentification to have increased rate limit. I still want to be able to use rtweet functions but with application-only-authentification. The only modification I need to do is to change a line of a internal function from  `r <- httr::GET(url, tokens)` to `r <- httr::GET(url, config = add_headers(my_headers))` where `my_header` is an object I defined that contains application-only-auth informations.

Comment: Based on your description, I might suggest a more robust option (if code safety is important for what you're building) is to fork rtweet on github, make that one simple change and install your forked version instead. You might also consider filing an issue suggesting this functionality be included, or if you know how submit a pull request.

Comment: Thank you @dww !

Is there a better way to do this than the one I am currently doing i.e create a new function identical to the one of the package and change just one line, then assigning Namespace of the package to this function ?

Answer (score 2):

This is normally not recommended but assuming you have a special situation that warrants it or for sake of answering the literal question asked:

```
my_func <- function(x) headers.response(x)
environment(my_func) <- asNamespace("httr")

# test
x <- list(headers = "X")
my_func(x)
## [1] "X"
```

or

```
my_func2 <- function(x) with(asNamespace("httr"), {
       headers.response(x)
})

# test
x <- list(headers = "X")
my_func2(x)
## [1] "X"
```

### Note

Depending on the specifics it may be possible to create a new class and your own method for that class:

```
    # define our own response2 class method for headers
    headers.response2 <- function(x) paste(x$header, ":", x$header2)

    # test - create a response2 object and then run headers on it
    library(httr)
    x <- structure(list(header = "X", header2 = "Y"), class = "response2")
    headers(x)
    ## [1] "X : Y"

This will only work if you can control the input.
```

- this is kludgy but you can use `trace` (see `?trace` for details) to insert code into a function you didn't write.  This can blow up on you if the target function changes in a manner not consistent with your patch but could be used as a stop gap.  In the example below we just printed out a message at the top but you can insert the code anywhere and use all the internal variables of the function.

  ```
  library(httr)

  trace(httr:::headers.response, quote(print("Hello from headers.response")))
  x <- structure(list(headers = "X"), class = "response")
  headers(x)
  ## Tracing headers.response(x) on entry 
  ## [1] "Hello from headers.response"
  ## [1] "X"
  ```

Comment: Thank you @G. Grothendieck.
This is the solution that I tried too, but I realized it didn't work just because I put a breakpoint in the body of my function.
Why is it not recommended ?

Comment: The second chunk in this code does not seem to work as the `with()` function does not transfer the x variable to the `asNamespace()`. From what I can see, the only reason that the code produces output is that `x <- list(headers = "X")` is stored with the same name that the function uses. if you change the code to
`y <- list(headers = "X")`

`my_func2(y)`
produces an error